# Enable duplicate values in select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 version 4.0 to add values it works fine. now I'm looking for any way to enable duplicate values to add same value but still haven't found any solution to do this.

How could I  enable duplicate values in select2 ?

Comment: Try setting a different key

Answer (score 0):

when you want to enable duplicate values to add same value .Review the following example.

```
 <select multiple>
    <option value="o">Orange</option>
    <option value="r">Red</option>
    <option value="r">Rose</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    $('select').select2();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but the values are returns from a database, how could I do ?